# Which Sprite would be rendered out of two overlapping sprites in a 2d world?

Tags: textures, sprites

For example, in a 2d setting, I have two sprites(one of green color and other of blue) of same size and y-axis and are at some distance apart from each other in x-axis. If there distance is gradually decreased and they overlap, will I see the blue sprite or green?

Comment: Does this represent what you are thinking?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/BOWNM.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the details of your rendering setup, but here are the most common out-of-the-box behaviours:

### 1. Painter's Algorithm

Many 2D frameworks simply layer sprites in the order they are drawn (so you need to draw your background before your foreground). In this case, whichever sprite occurs later in your drawing (ie. drawn from a later command, or from a later index in a batch) will overlap the earlier one.

If you're triggering your drawing through code, you can usually explicitly sequence your drawing calls to get the result you want. A graphical editor like Unity or Flash will usually have some concept of "layers" or ordering within layers, which allows you to control the drawing order. Other tools might have no explicit ordering control, so the drawing order is decided arbitrarily by the engine and might change at runtime.

### 2. Alpha Test With Depth Buffer

In frameworks with 3D capabilities, 2D sprites are sometimes drawn using a technique called Alpha Testing. In this case, any pixel with alpha below some threshold (often 50%) is skipped, while the rest are drawn fully-opaque in the frame buffer *and their depth is recorded in the depth buffer*.

This depth information can change what happens with subsequent sprites:

- If the depth test is set to `less-than-or-equal`, the results for sprites at the same depth will be the same as the painter's algorithm - the latter sprite will draw over the earlier one.
- If the depth test is set to `strictly-less`, then when the second sprite tries to draw, it will find another sprite already present at the intended depth, and those pixels will be skipped. This gives the opposite outcome to the painter's algorithm: the *first sprite will overlap later sprites* at the same depth. (or potentially [z-fight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) with them, depending on your camera & bias settings)

### 3. y-Sorted

Some frameworks & scripts for developing 2D games will automatically sort sprites by their y-coordinate, on the assumption that you're using an oblique or isometric map, where sprites at the top of the screen represent more distant objects, and those at the bottom of the screen represent closer objects.

[image: Example of y-sorting in a 2D game]

([Example from this devblog on sprite sorting](http://www.jakerobbins.net/20141123/layering-sprites-and-tiles/), although this case also includes a layer system)

It looks like this might be what's happening in the animated gif Jon has linked in the comments above. In this case, which sprite ends up on top depends on the particulars of the sorting algorithm used, and whether the two sprites are truly at exactly the same y-coordinate, not differing by a tiny fraction through rounding errors.

---

Of course, the fastest way to figure out what happens in your framework/engine of choice is to try it!

Comment: Thanks..  I'm using libgdx and it is using the painter's algorithm.  I learned a lot.